# jQuery .click() is triggering when selecting/highlighting text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a `<div>` with a bunch of text in it. This `<div>` also has a `.click()` event on it using jQuery.

The problem I'm having is that the `.click()` is being triggered when selecting/highlighting text. Even holding the mouse down for several seconds before releasing.

Here is a JSFiddle that shows the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ym5JX/

The behavior that I would expect is that highlighting text isn't the same as clicking on the element.

Comment: That's because a `click` is a `mousedown` followed by a `mouseup`.

Comment: `mousedown + mouseup = click.` Highlighting does it, so it is triggering click.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to stop the click happening? Only allow click if no text selected?

Comment: Not in my case (Opera). And btw, shouldn't `mousedown + mouseup = click` hold only if there is a small (system-definable) time delay between the events?

Comment: So is there any kind of work around?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish? Is the click event firing screwing something else up?

Comment: @j08691 yes, the click() event in my application changes that element to a textarea to become editable. I want the user to be able to highlight text (for say copying the text) without the click event triggering.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

That's because a `click` is a `mousedown` followed by a `mouseup`.  My suggestion is to check [`getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) inside the `click` handler.  If it's set, then you selected something, else you just clicked.

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    var sel = getSelection().toString();
    if(!sel){
        alert("clicked");
    }
});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ym5JX/3/

Comment: probably want to check the length   `haveSel = getSelection().toString().length > 0`

Comment: To not break the whole app when a user has text selected somewhere else it might be good to check that the selected text is in the relevant element: `if(!e.target.contains(getSelection().anchorNode))`.

Comment: Checking for selection elsewhere does not seem to be necessary. The reason is that a "true" click with clear any selection elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 8):

As I posted on comment, `mosuedown + mouseup = click` which is exactly what highlighting does. There is workaround for this.. see below,

```
var isClick = 0;
$('#click').click(function() {
    if (isClick == 1) {
        alert("clicked");
    }
}).mousedown(function () {
    isClick = 1;
}).mousemove(function () {
    isClick = 0;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ym5JX/6/)

Comment: Checking if the mouse moved between `mousedown` and `mouseup`, clever :-P

Answer (score 2):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ym5JX/8/

```
$('#click').click( function()
{
    if ( getSelection() == "" )
    {
        alert("clicked");
    }
});
```